# How to test a python script that reads from API, updates excel sheet, and uploads file to dropbox

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a very simple python script as shown below. All it does is read data from an API, add data to an excel file, and then uploads that excel file to dropbox. I'm aware that unit tests are supposed to be very simple in structure and only test one thing, with no dependencies on anything else (excel, dropbox). Is the only way I can test this script to do full integration tests, writing to an excel file and checking it, and the same for a dropbox folder?

```
def get_info(url):
    response = session.get(url)
    sold_units = json.loads(response.text)
    return info

def populate_excel_file(info):
    for unit in info:
        last_update_date = parser.parse(unit['lastupdatedate'])
        if now-timedelta(hours=24) <= last_update_date <= now:
            new_used = unit['NewUsed']
            make = unit['Make']
            model = unit['Model']
            model_year = unit['ModelYear']
            dsrp = unit['DSRP']
            row = sheet.max_row + 1
            sheet.cell(column=1, row=row, value=unit['lastupdatedate'])
            sheet.cell(column=2, row=row, value=make)
            sheet.cell(column=3, row=row, value=model)
            sheet.cell(column=4, row=row, value=model_year)
            sheet.cell(column=5, row=row, value=new_used)
            sheet.cell(column=6, row=row, value=dsrp)

    workbook.save(filename='BookNEW.xlsx')

def upload_file(file_from, file_to):
    dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(access_token)
    f = open(file_from, 'rb')
    dbx.files_upload(f.read(), file_to)

info = get_info("https://api.call")
populate_excel_file(info)

file_from = 'BookNEW.xlsx'
file_to = 'Book.xlsx'
upload_file(file_from, file_to)
```

Comment: Look into the concept of [mocking](https://realpython.com/python-mock-library/)

Comment: I also strongly suggest using a `with ... as` context manager for opening, reading, writing, and closing files.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Are you suggesting I mock the excel file? I already have a mock of the API response, but was unsure what to do with it. I'm also not sure how a mock would help test the dropbox API.